# How to get video size for HLS stream inside AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am trying to get video resolution when playing hls stream.
I have typical player init:

```
let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: currentVideoUrl)
 self.player=AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset:urlAsset))
 .......
```

I use KVO and i try to get video size when i get .ReadyToPlay status for AVPlayerItem:

```
    func resolutionSizeForVideo() {

    guard let videoTrack = self.player.currentItem?.asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first else
    { return
    }

    let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(videoTrack.naturalSize, videoTrack.preferredTransform)
    let frameSize = CGSize(width: fabs(size.width), height: fabs(size.height))
    print ("video size: \(frameSize)")

}
```

The problem is that tracksWithMediaType() always returns empty array (but works for non-stream files, e.g. for .mov).

How can i get size (CGRect) of the HLS video playing inside AVPlayer?

Comment: What do you mean by size?  The actual resolution of the video, or the rect of the player layer?

Comment: Video resolution, yes (edited the question).

Answer (score 15):

Are you able to log at least the video info using this method?

```
extension AVAsset{
    func videoSize()->CGSize{
        let tracks = self.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)
        if (tracks.count > 0){
            let videoTrack = tracks[0]
            let size = videoTrack.naturalSize
            let txf = videoTrack.preferredTransform
            let realVidSize = size.applying(txf)
            print(videoTrack)
            print(txf)
            print(size)
            print(realVidSize)
            return realVidSize
        }
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }

}

let videoAssetSource = AVAsset.init(URL: videoURL)
print("size:",videoAssetSource.videoSize())
```

Comment: The value returned for tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) on an m3u8 asset will be an empty array, so this code would result in an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: For HLS this let tracks = self.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video) will be an empty array.

Answer (score 14):

Tracks will always return nil when using HLS. If you have a UIView subclass that overrides its `layerClass` with an AVPlayerLayer for playing the video you can get the size with

```
playerView.layer.videoRect
```

This is the size of just the video and not the entire layer.

Alternatively you can use KVO to observe the presentationSize of the item

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.presentationSize", options: [.Initial, .New], context: nil)
```

Comment: I tried with KVO (presentationSize) before and it didn't return video resolution.

Comment: You can use player.currentItem.presentationSize getter any time, KVO is just for convenience. This will give you the resolution. Output from this command in a periodic observer is `print(self?.mediaPlayer?.currentItem?.presentationSize)` --> `Optional((853.333312988281, 480.0))
`

Comment: Made a comment saying that presentationSize was not the native size of the asset and that it was actually the size of the video in the player, but that doesn't seem correct. In my app the size that continues to get printed out is 1280x720 even when switching between landscape and portrait. Removed that previous comment since it was technically incorrect.

Comment: Just wanted to point something here - a KVO on `currentItem.presentationSize` is the correct way to do it , but it could still return `CGSizeZero` if the player item is NOT ready to play.

Comment: This doesn't provide access prior to display.

Answer (score 4):

You can concisely make it as so:

```
import AVKit

extension AVAsset {

    var videoSize: CGSize? {
        tracks(withMediaType: .video).first.flatMap {
            tracks.count > 0 ? $0.naturalSize.applying($0.preferredTransform) : nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a new implementation since iOS 16 because previous is deprecated (since iOS 16 and newer versions).

```
import AVKit
import Foundation

extension AVAsset {
    func videoSize() async throws -> CGSize? {
        guard let track = try await loadTracks(withMediaType: .video).first else { return nil }
        let size = try await track.load(.naturalSize)
        return size
    }
}
```